# Long Table Spans Two Pages

Tags: longtable, fontsize, cellsize

I would like to span a big table over two pages. When I use the longtable environment I cannot control the cell and font size. When I change the fontsize before the longtable starts font changes but the cell stay the same. Can someone help me to span the following table over two pages.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letter,notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{\\ Example of a Very Long Table}
\label{tab:long_tale}
\centering
\footnotesize

\begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lYYYY}
\hline \hline
& & & & \\
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
& & & & \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
& & & & \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tablenotes}

\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\item
\textit{Notes:} \lipsum[2-4]  

\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not going to happen, unless you manually split the contents over two table environments.  A better question is how to control the fontsize and cell (\arraystretch ?) with longtable.

Comment: There are longtable clones like ltxtable with support X (and therefore Y) columns.

Answer (score 1):

As @TrevorAndrew has already pointed out in a comment, you need to switch from a `table`/`tabularx` setup to a `longtable` setup.

Incidentally, I would place the long legend *outside* the `longtable`, in order to allow TeX to provide any needed pagebreaks freely, without being constrained by the `longtable` setup.

I would also align the numbers in the four data columns on their decimal markers.

I noticed that in your code, you set the width of the `tabularx` environment to `\textwidth`. I chose to mimic this behavior in the following code. Do let me know if this isn't necessary.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,booktabs,longtable,dcolumn} 
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{d{2.3}} @{}}
\caption{Example of a Very Long Table} \label{tab:long_tale} \\
\toprule
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{(Table \thetable, cont'd)} \\
\toprule
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\raggedleft\footnotesize\em Cont'd on following page} \\
\endfoot

Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\*  % prevent page break
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\
Example Variable & 0.49 &  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 \\
& (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) & (0.50) \\

\end{longtable}
\begingroup
\noindent\footnotesize
\textit{Notes for Table \thetable}: \lipsum[2-3]\par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I can have two horizontal lines on top and the bottom and no horizontal line after (1) (2) (3) (4)? Also how can I change the font and cell size, e.g. to footnotesize. And if you already set the size to footnotesize where do I see it?

Comment: @TrevorAndrew - Drawing two ill-spaced, thin horizontal lines instead of one well-spaced, slightly thicker horizontal line is nowadays considered to be rather old-fashioned. But if you insist, just replace both `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` with `\hline\hline`. If you don't want the line drawn by `\midrule`, then just omit both instances of that directive. If you want all material in the `longtable` environment to be rendered at footnote-type font size (why?), just insert `\begingroup\footnotesize` immediately before `\begin{longtable}` and `\endgroup` immediately after `\end{longtable}`.